# Cannot create new AzureVM using image captured using PowerShell

Tags: image, powershell, azure, virtual

I am not able to create new Azure VMs using images I have captured through PowerShell.

Here is the situation I am in.

1. I create 2 Windows VMs "mydevbox1" and "mydevbox2" using the latest image of Windows Server 2012 R2 in Azure gallery
2. I install necessary software and configure both exactly the same
3. 3a. I capture the the image of mydevbox1 called mydevbox1-image-PS using the powershell script below.
4. 3b. I capture the image of mydevbox2 called mydevbox2-image-Manual using the manual/portal process (sysprep -> capture image) (ofcourse I do it from a separate vm).
5. 4a. When I try to create a new vm using the mydevbox1-image-PS created through powershell, the VM creation process fails (provisioning times out)
6. 4b. When I try to create a new vm using the mydevbox2-image-Manual created through the manual process, the VM creation is successful.

Please help.

PowerShell Script I am using the capture the image

```
Save-AzureVMImage –ServiceName $serviceName_toCapture –Name $vmName_toCapture –ImageName $imageName_Captured_Generalized –OSState "Generalized" -ImageLabel $imageLabel_Captured_Generalized -Verbose
```

Comment: maybe try to call the cmdlet with -debug to get any additional error information.

Comment: This should be posted to ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

It fails because you didn't run sysprep before saving the image. The powershell cmdlet won't do it for you. -OSState parameter only saves the reference that the image was generalized or specialized. Details in this blog post:

**VM Image PowerShell ‘How To’ Blog Post**

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/01/vm-image-powershell-how-to-blog-post/

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do we need to go through the manual process of running sysprep every time before capturing the image? Is there a way to automate/script running fo the sysprep?

Comment: If you plan to use this image to create several others, yes! If you just want to redeploy the selected VM, you don't need to sysprep. The only way i can think of automating sysprep is by running it remotely using remote powershell sessions. http://michaelwasham.com/windows-azure-powershell-reference-guide/introduction-remote-powershell-with-windows-azure/. Then you can use this command Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\Sysprep.exe -ArgumentList '/generalize /oobe /shutdown /quiet'

Comment: I tried running the sysprep manually before capturing the image using powershell. It did not work.